# Schema.org: Can I use the type of Organization for a single man business?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

As a single man business, can I use the type [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)?

Currently, my website I used this JSON-LD schema to describe my business:

```
{
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"Organization",
   "@id":"https://example.com/#organization",
   "brand":{
      "@type":"Brand",
      "logo":"https://example.com/images/seo/home/logo.png",
      "image":"https://example.com/images/seo/home/og-image.jpg"
   },
   "description":"..,",
   "url":"https://example.com",
   "foundingDate":"2019-01-01",
   "logo":"https://example.com/images/seo/home/logo.png",
   "image":"https://example.com/images/seo/home/og-image.jpg",
   "contactPoint":[...],
   "sameAs":[...]
}

{
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"WebSite",
   "@id":"https://example.com",
   "url":"https://example.com",
   "author":{
      "@type":"Organization",
      "@id":"https://example.com/#organization"
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: https://technicalseo.com/tools/schema-markup-generator/ is a great tool for generating schema markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (Freelancer for example). Its better to use [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) (More specific type of Organization) -and even better to use **more specific type** of **LocalBusiness**  [Dentist](https://schema.org/Dentist) -or- [RealEstateAgent](https://schema.org/RealEstateAgent) for example.

Full Hierarchy example:
`Thing > Organization > LocalBusiness > MedicalBusiness > Dentist`

**LocalBusiness subtypes** ** 
https://schema.org/LocalBusiness#subtypes

** If your business type is not listed, choose a less specific type.

**Related:**

- **Local Business | Google Developers:** https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business